# How to find which serial port is in use?

Tags: devices, tty, serial-port

**The Question:**

I plugged in a device (i.e. GSM modem) through a serial port (a.k.a. RS-232), and I need to see with which file in `/dev/` filesystem this device was tied up, to be able to communicate with it. Unfortunately there is no newly created file in `/dev/` nor can be seen anything in `dmesg` output. So this seems to be a hard question.

**Background:**

I had never worked with a serial device, so yesterday, when there appeared a need, I tried to Google it but couldn't find anything helpful. I spent a few hours in seek, and I want to share a found answer as it could be helpful for someone.

Comment: I like using those bits to detect a device - I'll probably use that, although I've many devices that only use the Tx/Rx pins, I could probably hack them to hold the CTS line high for that.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unfortunately serial ports are non-PlugNPlay, so kernel doesn't know which device was plugged in. After reading a *[HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO.html)* tutorial I've got the working idea.

The `/dev/` directory of unix like OSes contains files named as *ttySn* *(with n being a number)*. Most of them doesn't correspond to existing devices. To find which ones do, issue a command:

```
$ dmesg | grep ttyS
[    0.872181] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    0.892626] 00:07: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    0.915797] 0000:01:01.0: ttyS4 at I/O 0x9800 (irq = 19) is a ST16650V2
[    0.936942] 0000:01:01.1: ttyS5 at I/O 0x9c00 (irq = 18) is a ST16650V2
```

Above is an example output of my PC. You can see the initialization of a few serial ports:

`ttyS0`, `ttyS1`, `ttyS4`, `ttyS5`.

One of them is [going to have a positive voltage](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-11.html) upon a device plugged in. So by comparing the content of the file `/proc/tty/driver/serial` with and without the device plugged in we can easily find the *ttyS* related to our device. So, now do:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial> /tmp/1
```

*(un)plug a device*

```
$ sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial> /tmp/2
```

Next check the difference between the two files. Below is an output of my PC:

```
$ diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2
2c2
< 0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:6 rx:0
---
> 0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:6 rx:0 CTS|DSR
```

By comparing the three numbers with the dmesg output we can determine which one is the port:

```
[    0.872181] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
```

Hence, our device is `/dev/ttyS0`, mission accomplished!

Comment: What if I don't see any device in the dmesg output?

Comment: @user3019105 sorry, I've never faced such issue. From what I understand, `dmesg` should have a message about assigning *irq* to a serial device. And if it didn't, I'd assume some hardware problem. That's just an assumption, and might be wrong, but if I'd debug such a problem, I'd start research with the idea in mind that serial port should've been initialized.

Comment: Since I move from machine to machine I have defined an alias to show me the serial ports on this machine.  It works on Ubuntu family systems with systemd.
alias ports='udevadm info --export-db |grep -i "^n: ttyu"'

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `setserial` to get and set serial port information, in addition to `dmesg`.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04:

### `setserial`

```bsh
# install it
sudo apt update
sudo apt install setserial

# Display (and sort) serial information for all /dev/ttyS* devices
setserial -g /dev/ttyS* | sort -V
# Display (and sort) serial information for all /dev/ttyUSB* devices
setserial -g /dev/ttyUSB* | sort -V

# To see extra info. such as the baud rate too, add `-G`:
setserial -g -G /dev/ttyS* | sort -V
setserial -g -G /dev/ttyUSB* | sort -V
```

Sample run and output. Notice that `/dev/ttyS4` is the only port that appears to be alive and not "unknown" (whatever that means). (This `/dev/ttyS4` device also shows up in the Arduino IDE even though it's not an Arduino and I don't know what it is.):

```bsh
$ setserial -g -G /dev/ttyS* | sort -V
/dev/ttyS0 uart unknown port 0x03f8 irq 4 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
/dev/ttyS1 uart unknown port 0x02f8 irq 3 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
/dev/ttyS2 uart unknown port 0x03e8 irq 4 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
/dev/ttyS3 uart unknown port 0x02e8 irq 3 baud_base 115200 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS4 uart 16550A port 0x3060 irq 19 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
/dev/ttyS5 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS6 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS7 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS8 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS9 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS10 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS11 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS12 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS13 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS14 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS15 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS16 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS17 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS18 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS19 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS20 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS21 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS22 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS23 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS24 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS25 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS26 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS27 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS28 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS29 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS30 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS31 uart unknown port 0x0000 irq 0 baud_base 0 spd_normal
```

### `dmesg`

Use `dmesg` to also see some of this information:

```bsh
# Show UART information, incl. baudrate, for /dev/ttyS* devices.
dmesg | grep ttyS

# Show UART information, incl. baudrate, for /dev/ttyUSB* devices.
dmesg | grep ttyUSB
```

Sample run and output:

```
$ dmesg | grep ttyS
[    1.624447] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS4 at I/O 0x3060 (irq = 19, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

Even better, **watch the `dmesg` kernel ring buffer output *live*** with the `-w` option:

```bsh
dmesg -wH
```

Now, unplug your USB device you're trying to identify and plug it back in to see which device it is, based on the messages that show up in the `dmesg` output, *live*.