# How to check if a COM port is being used

Tags: debian, serial-port

Im trying the check if a machine is connected to a device trough a COM port, i have tried comparing the `dmsg` output with the device plugged in and the output without the device plugged in, and they are exactly the same, so the output of dmsg never changes, the tty list in the dev directory never changes, no matter if its plugged in or not.How would i know which tty is COM1

I can do this either by python or bash.
Any help and suggestions are appreciated thanks

Comment: Are you trying to determine if there is a serial device plugged into your computer or that the interface in which you are connecting to another computer is serial?

Comment: i am trying to determine if there is a device connected to COM1 serial port

Comment: Does `cat /proc/tty/driver/serial` show anything with `CTS|DSR|CD`? Anther clue is to look for anything located under `/dev/serial`

Comment: doing ``` cat /proc/tty/driver/serial ```  shows 3 lines with CTS|DSR|CD , and there is no /dev/serial file or dir

Comment: my issue is than when i unplug or plug the device nothing changes, in the dmsg, in the /proc/tty/driver/serial file

Comment: `/dev/ttyS0` is `COM1`. As you were already told in another Q and which you seem to ignore, serial ports have **no** generic plug & play capabilities.

Comment: @Letho123 [Does this help?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125261/276845)

Comment: thank you kemotep, i will certainly try what you proposed, if it doesnt work, i think that its something that cant be done

Comment: The linked to answer doesn't work in the general case; a lot of devices that do not set or use the cts/dsr lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i check the model of a device connected to a specific COM trough a ssh connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524148/how-can-i-check-the-model-of-a-device-connected-to-a-specific-com-trough-a-ssh-c)